# Why do I receive Promise {<pending>} with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a very simple two methods in Vuejs and it returns me promise pending what I am doing it's this:

```
TotalIncomeData(day, branch_office_id) {
            return fetch('/api/collection/total/'+day+'/'+branch_office_id+'?api_token='+App.apiToken)
            .then(response => {
                    return response.data;
                }
    );
 },
 getTotalIncomes(day, branch_office_id) {
     console.log(this.TotalIncomeData(day, branch_office_id))
 },
```

Why am I not getting the value? Thanks

Comment: `TotalIncomeData` returns `fetch(...).then(...)`, which is a Promise. You should call its `then` function and put `console.log` there.

Comment: how can I remove it?

Comment: You're not getting the value because you don't await it or pass a callback to the then method to receive it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did this conseole.log(await this.TotalIncomeData(day, branch_office_id)) it displays an error

Comment: Is the error that you can't await in a non-async method? Because you can't await in a non-async method.

Comment: I suggest you read about what Promises are and how to use them properly, then you'll understand why your code doesn't work :)
[Guide from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.json()` on the fetch response, and await the result.

And you need to make your function async and `await` the promise from the first function.

```js
TotalIncomeData(day, branch_office_id) {
  return fetch(...).then(rawResponse => rawResponse.json())
                                                    ^^^^^^ 
 },
 async getTotalIncomes(day, branch_office_id) {
 ^^^^^
     console.log(await this.TotalIncomeData(day, branch_office_id))
                 ^^^^^
 },
```